# plotting multiple mean returns vs corresponding Standard deviations

Tags: r, plot

I´m currently working with 7 different datasets, therefore I have seven independent variables that represents the mean return for each dataset. 
The same thing goes for the Standard deviations.

I know how to plot for one value of mean return and the corresponding standard deviation;

```
plot=(meanr1, stdr1)
```

How do I plot all the mean returns versus their corresponding standard deviations?

```
from meanR1 ..to... meanR7 (mean returns)

from stdR1...to...stdR7   (standard deviation)
```

Comment: All in the same graph!

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is in R studio

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments, so that everything is in one place. Make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

A minimum solution (here for three means and stds) is

```
plot(c(meanR1,meanR2,meanR3),c(stdR1,stdR2,stdR3))
```

you may want to place the means and standard deviations in a dataframe first, e.g.

```
df<-data.frame(means=c(meanR1,meanR2,meanR3),stds=c(stdR1,stdR2,stdR3))
```

and then plot them using

```
plot(df$means,df$stds)
```